# C# -> COM -> change appointment -> exception when filling Start and End -> The object does not support this method

Tags: c#, outlook, com, outlook-object-model

i want to change an existing appointment. For this i search the existing appointment via:

```
                Outlook.Items foundItems = outlookItems.Restrict(filter);

            if (foundItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in foundItems)
                {
                    if (item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                    {
                        Outlook.AppointmentItem aptItem = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

                        aptItem.Start = start;
                    }
                }
            }
```

or:

```
foundItem = outlookItems.Find(filter) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
if (foundItem != null)
{foundItem.Start = start}
```

In any case, if i want to fill the appoitnment.Start property, it runs into this exception:

"The object does not support this method."

My thoughts were that it was a meeting, so I tried the following:

```
                Outlook.MeetingItem foundItem = outlookItems.Find(filter) as Outlook.MeetingItem;

            Outlook.AppointmentItem aptItem = foundItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(false);
```

But the foundItem was null, also no MeetingItem...

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Which folder is your code searching?

Comment: Hi Dimitry, i use the calendar folder: `ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)`

Comment: Update: this ecxeption occurs only with recurrence appointments

Comment: Update 2: this error also happens with this property: **AllDayEvent**

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found a solution by my selfe:

In case of an recurring appointment or meeting, i fill the properties **StartTime** and **EndTime** from the recurrencePattern:

```
                            newRecurrencePatternForOutlook.StartTime = start;
                        newRecurrencePatternForOutlook.EndTime = end;
```

But why the Start and End Property of the AppointmentItem does not exist, I cannot answer.

Maybe this will help someone